# Alias not working on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, mod-alias

I want to create an alias "/blog" to "/home/mydomain/blog" so when I request http://www.mydomain.ca/blog/myfile.html it returns /home/mydomain/blog/myfile.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.ca
    ServerAlias www2.mydomain.ca

    Alias "/blog" "/home/mydomain/blog"
    DocumentRoot "/home/mydomain/web"
    <Directory "/">
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/home/mydomain/web">
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
     <Directory "/home/mydomain/blog">
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www2.mydomain.ca [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.ca
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to request http://www.mydomain.ca/blog/myfile.html I get an error 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted the server? Set `LogLevel` to `info` and check access/error logs.

Comment: I get this www.mydomain.ca:443 [MY IP] - - [05/Jul/2016:17:47:23 +0000] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 404 2307 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/51.0.2704.79 Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Your server is listening at port 443, and the virtualhost is defined for port 80.

Comment: I change the virtualhost like this : "<VirtualHost *:443>" but I still get an error 404. Here is what I get : "www.mydomain.ca:443 [MY IP] - - [05/Jul/2016:19:42:39 +0000] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2307 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to add a line in **/etc/hosts** to declare www.mydomain.ca and www2.mydomain.ca are localhost

```
127.0.0.1    www.mydomain.ca   
127.0.0.1    www2.mydomain.ca
```

At least it worked for me